# Splice removing random elements issue in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, random, cart, splice

I am trying create interactive shopping cart using jQuery, but splice issue ruined everything, because when I am delete element directly it works perfect to me, but than I am going to dynamically changes it doesn't work deleting random elements in array even after updates indexes.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<div id="myDIV2"></div>
<div id="myDIV"></div>
<script>
 var wishlistArray = ["Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4", "Item5"];

 function wishlist_show() {

     var wishlistArrayDom = "";
     jQuery.each(wishlistArray, function (i, wishlistID) { 

         wishlistArrayDom += '<div><a href="javascript:;" class="rem-from-wishlist" value="' + i + '">Remove( ' + wishlistID + ' )</a></div>';
     });

     $('#myDIV').empty();
     $('#myDIV').html(wishlistArrayDom);
     wishlist_update_rem();

     console.log('All: ' + wishlistArray.length);
     console.log('Arr: ' + wishlistArray);
 }

 function wishlist_rem(num) {
     console.log('Value: ' + $(this).attr('value'));
     console.log('All: ' + wishlistArray.length);
     console.log('Arr: ' + wishlistArray);
     $(this).parent().slideUp("slow", function () {
         console.log(wishlistArray.splice($(this).attr('value'), 1));
         wishlist_show();

     });
     $('#myDIV2').append('<br>Remove ' + wishlistArray[parseInt($(this).attr('value'))] + ' of element' + +$(this).attr('value'));
 }

 wishlist_show();

 function wishlist_update_rem() {
     $(".rem-from-wishlist").unbind("click");
     $(".rem-from-wishlist").click(wishlist_rem);
 }
</script>
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/djga8h0u/) example

**UPDATE:** Solved by myself, thanks to all, stackoverflow is best.

Ready to used jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ar0zrxwc/

Comment: there is no issue, when you call to the function          wishlist_show(); you reasign the indexes for the values and creates the ilusion that splice is not working, but it is.. and is deleting the correct element, comment that line and you would see the expected behaviour, however you have to handle the new size of the array.. you should detect dynamically the index of the clicked element

Comment: @rahpuser that's not what's happening, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an issue with `splice()`, it's an issue with your scoping of `this`.

Change your removal function to this:

```
function wishlist_rem(num) {

     var idx = parseInt($(this).attr('value')));
     $(this).parent().slideUp("slow", function () {
         wishlistArray.splice(idx, 1));
         wishlist_show();

     });
     $('#myDIV2').append('<br>Remove ' + wishlistArray[parseInt($(this).attr('value'))] + ' of element' + +$(this).attr('value'));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `this` inside the animation callback is the parent of the element clicked which has no value attribute. Just define a variable at the same point that you are currently logging the index value.

```
 function wishlist_rem(num) {
     var index = parseInt( $(this).attr('value'),10);

     $(this).parent().slideUp("slow", function () {
         console.log(wishlistArray.splice(index, 1));
         wishlist_show();

     });
     $('#myDIV2').append('<br>Remove ' + wishlistArray[parseInt($(this).attr('value'))] + ' of element' + +$(this).attr('value'));
 }
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/djga8h0u/2/)**</kbd>